# Can't connect to MySQL server - PDO Connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Anyone can solve this problem?

```
Connection error, because: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'sample.com' (111)
```

The website has no problem before but this morning this error was found.
I found related topics but not found the right answer.

Comment: Looks like you have a network problem or the mysql server was stopped.

Comment: But how to solve if the mysql server was stopped?

Comment: You have to start it.